# Mojo::DOM extract paragraph after specific previous paragraph

Tags: perl, mojo-dom

Just using this Mojo::DOM for the first time and having trouble to extract information based on a previous tag. Looking for a way to grab 'The description'.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
require v5.10;
use feature qw(say);
use Mojo::DOM;

my $html = q(<p><strong>Description</strong></p><p>The description</p> <p><strong>Usage</strong></p><p>How to use this tool</p>);

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( $html );

say $dom->find('p strong')->map('text')->join("\n"); # Description
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the first one, you can do this

```
say $dom->at('p strong')->parent->next->text;
```

Or to get all of them

```
say $dom->find('p strong')->map(sub { $_->parent->next->text })->join("\n");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up using something like: 
`for my $e (Mojo::DOM->new($data)->find('a, p strong, p')->each) { say $e->all_text;}`